# Check whether string contains other than specific word

Tags: javascript

I need to check whether a string contains other than the specified words/sentence (javascript), it will return true if:

- it contains an alphabets, except this phrase: `ANOTHER CMD`
- it contains other than specified multiple sequence of numbers for example: `["8809 8805", "8806 8807"]` (the numbers are examples I should be able to test the string for any array of numbers)

Thank you!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: did you try [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) ?

Comment: It doesn't work, I want to check if a work is not included in the string whereas includes checks if it contains a string

Comment: !string.includes won't work because It can have unlimited number of unwanted words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can replace all not in the array

```js
const arr = ["ANOTHER CMD","8809 8805", "8809 8805"]
const okContent = str => { 
  arr.forEach(entry => str = str.replaceAll(entry,""))
  return str.trim()==="";
};

console.log(okContent('Has other stuff than ANOTHER CMD and 8809 8805'))
console.log(okContent('8809 8805 ANOTHER CMD 8809 8805'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the correct way of doing it but this worked for me:

- replace all the valid words with balnk (using `replace`)
- check if the string is left empty
- if it's empty, it means that the string does not contain any unwanted string (to check for space you could use `trim` method)

Answer (score 0):

you can try regex!

use your array of strings as the '|' separated regex value

and check the specified string in the given line. if it presents negate the output.

```js
const regex = /(ANOTHER CMD|8809 8805|8806 8807)/i
console.log(!regex.test('Should not contain word ANOTHER CMD'))

console.log(regex.test('Should contain word ANOTHER CMD'))
```

Comment: yes! check here: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3y9je7zu7

Comment: I think the problem here is we could use the same variable to test twice.

Comment: refer: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3y9jedy6u

Comment: I found the issue with my regex, I have made an edit you can check now!

Comment: There is a problem , I want to make sure that the string only contains: `ANOTHER CMD` or numbers: `["8809 8805", "8806 8807"]`